# How to use Form Input when Posting through Ajax and not through Submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-ajax

The issue appears deceptively simple: I need a `CaseId` as input when uploading and uploading a file to the server and storing its information in a table called FilePath.

I have created a View (Index) with a Form that sends its input to the view `UplaodDnD`, where a file can be uploaded through DragnDrop. The DragnDrop is managed through a Jquery/Ajaxscript. That script calls the UploadDnD POST Action, but for some reason does not store the passed through CaseID-field.

The controller assures the actual uploading of the file and assigns values to some fields of the FilePath Model. I thought that adding the CaseID-field to the UploadDnD-form should do the trick, but apparantly not. How should I assign the pass on the caseId to the FilePath?

My code on the index-page to fire of the required caseId:

```
<form method="post" action="UploadDnD/UploadDnD">
    <div>Please provide CaseId</div>
    <input type="number" name="caseId" />    
    <input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

The `UploadDnd` page has the following code:

```
@model BeagleNose.Models.FilePath
@{ViewData["Title"] = "Index";}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="fileBasket" class="filebasket">
       Drag-n-Drop files here.
       <br /><br /><br />
       End of Dropzone
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <input asp-for="CaseID" value="@ViewBag.selectedCase"class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <img id="progress" src="~/Images/progress.gif" />
</form>
```

The UploadDnD Action Methods of Get and Post

```
public IActionResult UploadDnD(int? caseId)
    {
        if(caseId != null)
        {
            ViewBag.selectedCase = caseId;
        }
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UploadFiles([Bind("CaseID,CandidateID,ArchiveSet")] FilePath filePath)
        {
        long size = 0;
        var files = Request.Form.Files;  

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string filename = hostingEnv.WebRootPath + $@"\bcontent\{file.FileName}";
            size += file.Length;
            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Flush();
            }

            filePath.FileName = file.FileName;
            filePath.FileType = FileType.ContractFile;
            filePath.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            filePath.DocPath = filename;
            _context.Add(filePath);
        }
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        string message = $"{files.Count} files(s) / {size} bytes uploaded successfully!";
        return Json(message);
    }
```

And finally the Jquery/Ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#progress").hide();

$("#fileBasket").on("dragenter", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

$("#fileBasket").on("dragover", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

$("#fileBasket").on("drop", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();

    var files = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var fileNames = "";

    if (files.length > 0) {
        fileNames += "Uploading <br />"
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileNames += files[i].name + "<br />"
        }
    }
    $("#fileBasket").html(fileNames)

    var data = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/UploadDnD/UploadFiles",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (message) {
            $("#fileBasket").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#fileBasket").html
                ("There was error uploading files!");
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#progress").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#progress").hide();
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you form

```
<input type="number" name="caseId" id="caseId" />
```

Before your AJAX call just append its value to data.

```
data.append("caseId", $("#caseId").val());
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/UploadDnD/UploadFiles",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (message) {
            $("#fileBasket").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#fileBasket").html
                ("There was error uploading files!");
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#progress").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#progress").hide();
        }
    });
```

You will get caseId in controller. Hope this helps.

Comment: It doe the trick! Thank you. Now my next step will be to see if I can pass it directly into the controller, without using it in the view (appears more secure to me).

Comment: Good luck. If you need any help you can ask here. :) @CharlesdeM.